# What happens to an in-progress `7-day phased release` on the App Store when a newer version is published?

Tags: app-store-connect

Curious what would happen when version 1.1 is on **day 2 out of 7 of a 7-day phased rollout** in the App Store, and you publish a 1.2 upgrade.

Would it:

A. Immediately release 1.1 to the remaining 80% of users?

B. Leave the 80% of users on 1.0 until they get 1.2?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software as defined in the Help Center.

Comment: @fsb The help center says Apple Services are in scope and paying to be a developer and using the App Store is one of Apple's services. We can discuss on [meta] if needed. The only programming items that are off topic are code level questions - this is about policy and services as I read it.

Comment: @bmike The question was edited with more info after I voted to close it.  At the time, there was no reference to the Apple, the App Store, or even what this question was actually about. Now that it's been edited, I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: @fsb Sounds great - glad the edit makes it clearer - those are the best edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would not immediately release 1.1.

If your publish 1.2 with immediate availability, then all users will be upgraded to 1.2 the next time the auto-update process on their decice kicks in. This means that both 1.0 and 1.1 users would be updated at the same time.

If you publish 1.2 with phased roll-out, then that phased roll out will run independently from the other one. I.e. 1.1 is not released immediate to the remaining users, nor are users left on 1.0 until they get 1.2.

Comment: Think your third paragraph should begin "If you publish 1.2" not "If you publish 1.1".

Comment: Exactly - corrected it now!